# Get value of a form input by ID python/flask

Tags: python, html, flask

How do you get the actual value of the `input` id after you send it in Flask?

form:

```
<form  action="" method="post">
    <input id = "number_one" type="text" name="comment">
    <input type="submit" value = "comment">
</form>
```

like, what I am trying to say is when the form is sent (i.e. when you do this):

```
request.form.get("comment")
```

the value of the text field is passed. What I can't figure out is how to get the value of the `id`.

So, when the form is sent we could then tell from which form the info was coming from, because each form has a unique `id`. In this case the `id` is `number_one`.

So, how do we go about getting the actual literal value of the `id` and not the text input?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't. The `id` value is not part of the form data set sent by the browser.

If you need to identify the field, you'll have to either add the id to the `input` element name, or if the `id` is generated by Javascript code, perhaps store the information in an extra hidden field.

Adding the id to the name could be done with a delimiter perhaps:

```
<input id = "number_one" type="text" name="comment.number_one">
```

which would require you to loop over all form keys:

```
for key is request.form:
    if key.startswith('comment.'):
        id_ = key.partition('.')[-1]
        value = request.form[key]
```

Comment: so i'll just make a hidden field and just throw in the `id` in there?. in this case how would that go? like this? `
`<input type="hidden" name="id" value="number_one" ></input>`

I tried this right now I still couldn't get the `value`

Comment: @Zion: you'd have to devise a mapping scheme. Perhaps name the hidden input `comment_id`, so you can use `id_ = request.form['comment_id']` to get it.

Comment: @Zion: and the HTML would be `<input type="hidden" name="comment_id" value="number_one" />`, input tags are empty.

Comment: actually I tried this 
`<input type ="hidden" value= "number_one" name = "form_id">`
and using that for loop you suggested the only `key` in the `form` was `comment`.   `form_id` wasn't even seen

Comment: @Zion: what I suggest in my answer is a **different** approach, distinct from the hidden field option.

Comment: Im actually surprised this is tougher than I thought. I'll get back to this and do more reasearch because using the hidden field didn't work which is odd

Comment: @Zion: the hidden field worked just fine. You just misunderstood that I am talking about two different options. You can use `comment = request.form.get('comment')` and `id_ = request.form.get('form_id')` when using your hidden input approach.

Comment: @Zion: I was taking into account that perhaps you were generating more than one field in Javascript and needed to a more complex scheme to track an id *per form element generated*.

Comment: I feel so dumb the reason why it didn't work because I was looking at the wrong template when doing the hidden field route. but now it does. wow fml

Answer (score 0):

There is a one way to identify the **fields** and also **multiple forms** together....

use this

```
<input value = "1" type="hidden" name="my_id">
```

so at your **view** file you can retrieve this value.

```
my_id = request.form.get("my_id","")
print my_id
```

your output will be

```
1
```

you can also do this...

```
my_id = request.form.get("my_id","")
if my_id == "1":

    ** for example **

    value = request.form.get("any_parameter_of_form","")
```

Comment: In your example, what object type is `my_id`? is it string or numeric?